# Invalid syntax error, but python fails to be helpful, as usual

Tags: python, encryption

Code is as following:

```
cryptograph = {"a":"b", "b":"c", "c":"d", 'd': 'e', 'e':'f', 'f':'g', 'g':'h', 'h':'i', 'i':'j', 'j':'k', 'k':'l', 'l':'m', 'm':'n', 'n':'o', 'o':'p', 'p':'q', 'q':'r', 'r':'s', 's':'t', 't':'u', 'u':'v','v':'w', 'w':'x', 'x':'y', 'y':'z', 'z':'a', ' ': ' ', '.':',', ',':'.', '"':"'", "'":'"', '<':'>', '>':'<', '0':'1', '9':'2', '8':'3', '7':'4', '6':'5', '5':'6', '4':'7', '3':'8', '2':'9', '1':'0'}

def encrypt (string):
    string = string.lower()
    length = len(string)
    toBeTranslated = splitter(string)
    translated = ''

    for letter in toBeTranslated:
        translated = translated + cryptograph[letter]
    print(translated)

def decrypt (string):
    string = string.lower()
    length = len(string)
    toBeTranslated = splitter(string)    
    translated = ''

    for letter in toBeTranslated:
        translated = translated + list(cryptograph.keys())[list(cryptograph.values()).index[letter]



def splitter (string):
    rotation = 0
    stringLength = len(string)
    charList = []
    for _ in range(stringLength):
        charList.append(string[rotation])
        rotation = rotation + 1
    return charList
```

Whenever i run it, it gives me an "invalid syntax" syntax error, but fails to show me what i did wrong.

When run in IDLE, the code is meant to encrypt and decrypt strings. I just added the decrypt function, and prior to that it worked fine (as in it encrypted things.)

I have checked indentures and colons, and found no errors.

Thanks in advance,
          mrdorkface

Comment: noticed all kinds of small stuff wrong (string mispelled, hi instead of cryptograph [copied it from test code in IDLE, forgot to change names]) and will change it

Comment: you have a missing square close bracket in your for loop inside of decrypt

Comment: Python is usually very helpful, but syntax errors are the first hurdle.

Comment: Thank you R Nar. code will now initialize in IDLE

Comment: @Peter yeah, learning the syntax can be hard, and the website i learned it from uses a slightly outdated version, so i had to relearn some things.

Comment: Delete everything before the syntax error, then gradually add it back.

Comment: @mrdorkface the syntax hasn't changed that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see this, it is **usually** because I have an unbalanced bracket. Just put your cursor on the character before where it said you have an error and type "]" and see if IDLE highlights code back to somewhere. There is your unbalanced bracket that is causing the error. If it doesn't highlight but instead beeps, delete the "]" and try ")" and then "}". Usually this finds your problem.

I did that and immediately found the line with the problem:

```
translated = translated + list(cryptograph.keys())[list(hi.values())].index[letter]
```

Is missing a closing "]"

Answer (score 2):

A quick look says your missing some closing brackets on the line
`translated = translated + list(cryptograph.keys())[list(hi.values()).index[letter]`

Verify that all of your open and close brackets match up for everything.

Answer (score 2):

this line is missing a bracket:

```
        translated = translated + list(cryptograph.keys())[list(hi.values())].index[letter]
```